# Java rmi: не могу возвратить объект

Tags: rmi, java, объекты

Здравствуйте. При реализации удаленного интерфейса rmi столкнулся с проблемой: мои удаленные методы возвращают без проблем примитивные типы, такие как int, char и т.д., а когда надо возвращать Object test = new Object(), то выдает ошибку:

```
 java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling return; nested exception is: 
    java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: java.lang.Object
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:173)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:178)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:132)
    at $Proxy0.func(Unknown Source)
    at rmiclient.Consol$TestActionListener.actionPerformed(Consol.java:107)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1995)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2318)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6289)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3267)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6054)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2041)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4652)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2099)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4482)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4577)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4238)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4168)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2085)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2478)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4482)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:644)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:85)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:603)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:601)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:617)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:615)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:614)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
Caused by: java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: java.lang.Object
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1332)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:350)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.unmarshalValue(UnicastRef.java:306)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:155)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: java.lang.Object
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1164)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:330)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.marshalValue(UnicastRef.java:274)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:315)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:159)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:155)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:535)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:790)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:649)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

даже не могу предположить в чем может быть проблема. Что нибудь подскажете?

**Добавлено.**

Работаю в netbeans. Сначала запускаю server, в котором находится удаленный интерфейс и удаленные компоненты (реализация интерфейса).

```
public interface MyRemoteInterface extends Remote {
    public Object func (int k) throws RemoteException;
}

public class MyRemoteComponent extends UnicastRemoteObject implements  MyRemoteInterface {
    public Object func (int k) 
    { 
        Object p=new Object();
        return p; 
    }
}
```

Потом запускаю клиент (run). Без каких либо параметров. В клиенте находится тот же удаленный интерфейс и вызов функции:

```
Object y = remoteComponent.func(100);
```

Вот собственно и все.

*Добавлено:

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("temp.out");
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
TestSerial ts = new TestSerial();
oos.writeObject(ts);
oos.flush();
oos.close();
```

Comment: Дабавьте в классПатч для сервера те обьекты которые вы используете в клиенте.

Comment: Прошу прощения, но можно поподробнее. Просто я второй день использую rmi.

Comment: Расскажите подробно что и как вы запускаете, и с какими параметрами

Comment: Работаю в netbeans. Сначала запускаю server в котором находится удаленный интерфейс и удаленные компоненты (реализация интерфейса).

public interface MyRemoteInterface extends Remote {
    public Object func (int k) throws RemoteException; }

public class MyRemoteComponent extends UnicastRemoteObject     implements MyRemoteInterface {
      public Object func (int k) { Object p=new Object();
         return p; }
}
потом запускаю клиент (run). без каких либо параметров. в клиенте находится тот же удаленный интерфейс и вызов функции

Object y = remoteComponent.func(100);

вот собственно и все.

Comment: А сам rmiregistry как запускаете ?
Отдельно через cmd ? Или тоже через java проект ?

Comment: Через java проект. Командную строку не использую вообще.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В общим вот специально для вас склепал маленький helloWorld

первым делом запускаем сам registryService этим файлом:

**RegistryService.java**

```
package server;

import client.TestObject;
import java.rmi.Naming;
import java.rmi.NotBoundException;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.io.Serializable;

import java.util.*;

public class TestService implements TestServiceInterface, Serializable {

    Map testServiceListenerQueueMap = new HashMap();

    public TestService() throws Exception {
        init();
        unBindFromRegistry();
        bindToRegistry();
    }

    private void init() throws Exception {

    }

    public String test() throws RemoteException {
        System.out.println( "test" );
        return "Hello";
    }

    public TestObject test2() throws RemoteException {
        return new TestObject();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final TestService t = new TestService();
        t.startLiveLoop();
        t.unBindFromRegistry();
    }

    public void startLiveLoop() {
        Thread cMainThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while (Thread.currentThread() != null) {
                try {
                    //Thread.sleep(10000);
                    Iterator itr = testServiceListenerQueueMap.keySet().iterator();
                    while (itr.hasNext()) {
                        try {
                            String name = (String) itr.next();
                            // Ваши какие то действия для очереди сообщений
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }});

        cMainThread.setName("Live Loop");
        //Start the thread
        cMainThread.start();

        try {
            cMainThread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    protected void bindToRegistry() {
        boolean bound = false;
        while (!bound) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Trying to bind " + BIND_NAME);
                java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(this);
                java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry.getRegistry().bind(BIND_NAME, this);
                bound = true;
                System.out.println("Successfully called bind() for " + BIND_NAME);
            }catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println("Could not bind " + BIND_NAME + ", trying to rebind");
                try {
                    java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry.getRegistry().rebind(BIND_NAME, this);
                    bound = true;
                    System.out.println("Successfully called rebind() for " + BIND_NAME);
                }catch (Exception ex2) {
                    System.out.println("Could not rebind " + BIND_NAME);
                    ex2.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            //Sleep a little before attemping to bind again.
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            }catch (Exception ex1) {
                ex1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    protected void unBindFromRegistry() {
        try {
            System.out.println("Trying unbind() for " + BIND_NAME);
            java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry.getRegistry().unbind(BIND_NAME);
            System.out.println("Successfully called unbind() for " + BIND_NAME);
        }catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Could not unbind() for " + BIND_NAME);
        }
    }

    public void ping() {
        //System.out.println("ping() :" + getClass().getName());
    }    
}
```

Затем запускаем это:

```
package server;

import client.TestObject;
import java.rmi.Naming;
import java.rmi.NotBoundException;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.io.Serializable;

import java.util.*;

public class TestService implements TestServiceInterface, Serializable {

    Map testServiceListenerQueueMap = new HashMap();

    public TestService() throws Exception {
        init();
        unBindFromRegistry();
        bindToRegistry();
    }

    private void init() throws Exception {

    }

    public String test() throws RemoteException {
        System.out.println( "test" );
        return "Hello";
    }

    public TestObject test2() throws RemoteException {
        return new TestObject();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final TestService t = new TestService();
        t.startLiveLoop();
        t.unBindFromRegistry();
    }

    public void startLiveLoop() {
        Thread cMainThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while (Thread.currentThread() != null) {
                try {
                    //Thread.sleep(10000);
                    Iterator itr = testServiceListenerQueueMap.keySet().iterator();
                    while (itr.hasNext()) {
                        try {
                            String name = (String) itr.next();
                            // Ваши какие то действия для очереди сообщений
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }});

        cMainThread.setName("Live Loop");
        //Start the thread
        cMainThread.start();

        try {
            cMainThread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    protected void bindToRegistry() {
        boolean bound = false;
        while (!bound) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Trying to bind " + BIND_NAME);
                java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(this);
                java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry.getRegistry().bind(BIND_NAME, this);
                bound = true;
                System.out.println("Successfully called bind() for " + BIND_NAME);
            }catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println("Could not bind " + BIND_NAME + ", trying to rebind");
                try {
                    java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry.getRegistry().rebind(BIND_NAME, this);
                    bound = true;
                    System.out.println("Successfully called rebind() for " + BIND_NAME);
                }catch (Exception ex2) {
                    System.out.println("Could not rebind " + BIND_NAME);
                    ex2.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            //Sleep a little before attemping to bind again.
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            }catch (Exception ex1) {
                ex1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    protected void unBindFromRegistry() {
        try {
            System.out.println("Trying unbind() for " + BIND_NAME);
            java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry.getRegistry().unbind(BIND_NAME);
            System.out.println("Successfully called unbind() for " + BIND_NAME);
        }catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Could not unbind() for " + BIND_NAME);
        }
    }

    public void ping() {
        //System.out.println("ping() :" + getClass().getName());
    }    
}
```

Ну и сам файл интерфейса:
**TestServiceInterface.java**

```
package server;

import client.TestObject;
import java.rmi.Remote;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;

public interface TestServiceInterface extends Remote{

    public static final String BIND_NAME = "testRMI";

    public String test() throws RemoteException;
    public TestObject test2() throws RemoteException;
    public void ping() throws RemoteException;

}
```

Теперь сервер запущен.

Запускаем клиент
**Client.java**

```
package client;

import java.rmi.Naming;
import server.TestServiceInterface;

public class Client {

    TestServiceInterface test;
    String RMIURL = "rmi://localhost/" + TestServiceInterface.BIND_NAME;

    public TestServiceInterface getTest() throws Exception {
        int attempts = 0;
        while (attempts < 5) {
            try {
                test.ping();
                attempts++;
                Thread.sleep(100);
                break;
            }catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println("===> TestClient Connection failed! Reconnecting...");
                test = (TestServiceInterface) Naming.lookup( RMIURL );
            }
        }
        return test;
    }

    public void test(){
        try{
            getTest();
            System.out.println( test.test() );
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void test2(){
        try{
            getTest();
            TestObject to = test.test2();
            System.out.println( to.t );
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Client c = new Client();
        c.test();
        c.test2();
    }

}
```

**TestObject.java**

```
package client;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class TestObject implements Serializable {

    public String t  = "Hello World";

}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Хоть возникло вопросов больше чем ответов, но он работает. И это хорошо)

Answer (score 0):

Хм, с rmi практически не работал, но исходя из общей эрудиции, мне кажется, что `Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: java.lang.Object` говорит само за себя - для работы rmi необходимо, чтобы передаваемые объекты были сериализуемы, т.е. реализовывали интерфейс [Serializable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html).

Comment: Как я понимаю, оно требует выполнения механизма сериализации объектов. Но он требует обязательного создания внешнего файла, через которого и проходит собственно весь механизм. Вопрос: зачем для передачи объекта через удаленный интерфейс мне использовать внешние файлы? По-моему это не логично. Обойти это как-то можно?

Comment: О каких внешних файлах вы говорите? Сериализация необходима, чтобы была возможность упаковать объекты (аргументы и вовращаемые значения) в блоки байт для передачи на другой конец через сеть. Или вы о заглушках/стабах? По-моему, это один из моментов спецификации и без них не обойтись.

Comment: Если упаковывать таким образом (добавлено в главное сообщение), то создается двоичный файл temp.out. Про него я говорил. Куда можно запаковать эти "блоки байт", кроме как в файл, и как, чтобы послать или получить?